i am facing problem in combining the forecasts generated by multiple stacked GRU models
first i have used CEEMDAN, to decompose multi-variate data into different IMFs, after that for each IMF stacked GRU model is trained, which gives results for each IMFs,
for the final predictions i need to combine these results using bagging-boosting ensemble strategy, is it feasible?
